# Why $z=0$ is a removable singularity of $\frac{iz-e^{iz}+1-\frac{z^2}{2}}{z^3}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Why $z=0$ is a removable singularity of $$\frac{iz-e^{iz}+1-\frac{z^2}{2}}{z^3}$$

I tried to show $\lim_{z\to 0}z\frac{iz-e^{iz}+1-\frac{z^2}{2}}{z^3}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{iz-e^{iz}+1-\frac{z^2}{2}}{z^2}=0$, however, I cannot see why this limit is $0$?

Could anyone kindly help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$e^{iz} = 1+iz-{1 \over 2!} z^2 - i {1 \over 3!} z^3 + \sum_{k=4}^\infty {1 \over k!} (iz)^k$.

Let $g(z) = - i {1 \over 3!} + \sum_{k=4}^\infty {1 \over k!} (iz)^{k-3}$
and note that $g$ is entire.

Note that ${e^{iz} - 1-iz+{1 \over 2!} z^2 \over z^3} = g(z) $ for $z \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Series solution ...
$$
e^{iz} = 1 + iz +\frac{(iz)^2}{2}+\frac{(iz)^3}{6}+o(z^3)
$$
Can you go from here?